# How to record video on Safari iOS using MediaRecorder

Tags: javascript, amazon-s3, mime-types, recordrtc, mediarecorder-api

I am making a video recording website, and using the recordRTC package, I have it working on chrome desktop and android. However, this package does not work on safari either on desktop or iOS. I have tried using the mediaRecorder API, and have a working prototype where I am able to record on iOS Safari, using mediaRecorder with mimeType video/mp4, and can playback the created blob, but when I try to upload my video to my AWS S3 bucket I get the error "Demuxer: [ReadPacketData File read failed - end of file hit at length [928731]. Is file truncated?]"
Has anyone seen this error before?
Is there any other way to record video on Safari iOS?

Comment: sounds like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66262625/aws-mediaconvert-fails-when-transcoding-a-video-created-from-an-ios-safari-webrt